# Convergence in a complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis

I have two related questions.  The first one is, show that if $(X, \rho)$ is a complete metric space and $\{ x_{n} \}$ is a sequence satisfying $\rho(x_{n}, x_{n+1}) < 2^{-n}$, then $\{ x_{n} \}$ converges.  The second one is to find an example of a sequence $\{ x_{n} \}$ in a complete metric space such that $\rho(x_{n}, x_{n+1}) < 1/n$ and yet $\{ x_{n} \}$ does not converge.

I am thinking that the reason these two facts are true is something similar to the reason that the harmonic series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} $ does not converge but $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}} $ does converge.  However, I cannot see how to prove the first fact or come up with a counterexample for the second fact.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem, you need to show $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, so fix $\epsilon > 0$, then note that if $n>m$,
$$
\rho(x_n,x_m) \leq \sum_{j=m}^n \frac{1}{2^j} \leq \sum_{j=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^j} \qquad (\ast)
$$
Being the tail of a convergent  series, for $\epsilon > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\sum_{j=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^j} < \epsilon
$$
From this and $(\ast)$, it follows that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and hence convergent.

For the second problem, I will just give a hint: You mention the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}
$$
Can you use this very example to find what you want in $\mathbb{R}$ (which is complete with respect the usual metric)?

Comment: Ah, I see it now, thanks!!